# Use a DLL generated by IKVM

Tags: java, c++, dll, ikvm

I have generated a DLL froma JAR file using IKVM doing:

ikvmc -target:library mylib.jar

I would like to use the DLL in a Visual C++ project. What are the steps required to call dll functions from my own code? How do I know which methods are exported by the DLL and how do I call them without a header file?

Answer (score 1):

The IKVM.NET is written for the .NET framework 2.0. The usage inside a Visual Studio C++ project can be difficult. But it should be possible [to access it via COM interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14975883/12631). Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14975883/12631).